# Android WebView upload file

Tags: android, html, webview, upload, chinese-locale

I had "upload file success" with WebView which loaded the html5 page. But I have a problem in the code. My code as follows:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_card);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true); // 设置允许访问文件数据
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new XHSWebChromeClient());

/**
 * More info this method can be found at
 * http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
 *
 * @return 创建的文件
 * @throws IOException
 */
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.CHINESE).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File storageDir = new File(sdcard + "/WeiJuMei/Download");
    return File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : data.getData();
            if (result == null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                mUploadMessage = null;
                return;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult" + result.toString());
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, result);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                mUploadMessage = null;
                return;
            }
            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult after parser uri:" + uri.toString());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                //                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{uri});

                if (/*requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE ||*/ mUploadMessage == null) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    return;
                }

                Uri[] results = null;

                // Check that the response is a good one
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                        if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = data.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                //                mUploadMessage = null;
                //                return;

            } else {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(uri);
            }
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(uri);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            mUploadMessage = null;
            return;
        }
    }
}

public class XHSWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int newProgress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        super.onProgressChanged(webView, newProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView webView, String s, String s1, JsResult jsResult) {
        return super.onJsAlert(webView, s, s1, jsResult);
    }

    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        Log.i(TAG, "in openFile Uri Callback");
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
    }

    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "in openFile Uri Callback has accept Type" + acceptType);
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        String type = TextUtils.isEmpty(acceptType) ? "*/*" : acceptType;
        i.setType(type);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
    }

    // For Android 4.1
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
        Log.i(TAG, "in openFile Uri Callback has accept Type" + acceptType + "has capture" + capture);
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        String type = TextUtils.isEmpty(acceptType) ? "*/*" : acceptType;
        i.setType(type);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
    }

    // Android 5.0+
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;
    }
}
```

When choosing native image with Chinese path I found upload image was failing, but english path is successful, Why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe add a flag like Chinese?

Comment: What can I do in my code?

Comment: Sorry meant to say "Maybe add a tag to the question like 'Chinese' or something" so that someone with experience can see it and be able to help.